# Importing WKB data into ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, csv, well-known-binary

I have received a CSV data file with the geographical data column in WKB format.

How can I import this into ArcGIS Pro or is is some conversion tool required before I can import this into ArcGIS?

[image: Sample of data in WKB format]

Comment: That's not WKB, it's hexadecimal ASCII of WKB. `arcpy.FromWKB()` works if it's actually binary data in WKB format.

Comment: and hex string to byte conversion is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649407/hexadecimal-string-to-byte-array-in-python